# Sin cos function giving wrong results for degrees greater than 90

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

When I use

```
cout<<"Cos: "<<cos(_theta)<<" Sin: "<<sin(_theta)<<endl;
```

where _theta = 180, it gives output,

```
Cos: -0.59846 Sin: -0.801153
```

But the output should be

```
Cos: -1 Sin: 0
```

I don't understand why this is happening!

Comment: I'm assuming you're storing theta in degrees? If so, you need to convert it to radians when using the C trig functions.

Comment: the way you are using it you get wrong results for almost any angle. The parameters passed should be in radians not degree

Comment: You are right! Silly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions cos and sin receive angles in radians instead of degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Ask google about "cos(180)"   => -0.59846006905
It's because it using radians and not degrees.
In radians, 180° is half a circle, so it's pi, ask google cos(pi) => -1
:)